# iPhone-like navigation dots for Android

Tags: iphone, android, image-gallery

I have to create an image gallery that navigation dots like the iPhone gallery.

Check out the screenshot. I need such a widget, look at the white dots:

[image: iPhone-like image gallery in Android with navigation dots]

Is there any widget available in Android that includes navigation dots? If not, how can I recreate this effect?

Comment: You need to create a custom one yourself or use something like this with numbers < 1/12 > where the number reflects the current position out of the total.

Comment: Any thoughts on these answers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After Long days i found [View Pager Navigation Dots from Github source](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have imported Github library and sample project in eclipse. library giving error "R can't be resolved to a variable. any one can help"

Answer (score 1):

On my Arcos Tablet there is something like this used for the homescreen navigation - I am afraid it might be a custom widget though so you might have to write it yourself ...

If you know the name of the iPhone widget which does what you want (IF there is a particular name for it) - then google that in the following fashion: widgetName+for android - or something like this - I guess you're getting the idea :).

Answer (score 1):

This link could be usefull : [Android Scroll Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966775/android-scroll-pagination)

Check out for : UipageControl (within UiScrollView). That's the name of the IPhone Class.

Comment: No, not yet. I keep hoping i could find a better solution before trying to implement this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that really easily using the GreenDroid library. Example: 
https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid/blob/master/GDCatalog/src/com/cyrilmottier/android/gdcatalog/PagedViewActivity.java

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a custom component that uses View.ViewPager, which is part of the android [compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html). An example of this can be found [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own one... or google about it :)

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-imageview-example

you may not find exactly what you look for but you can style the controls as you like ;)